# UIcollectionView Cell's subview resize to fit cell size

Tags: ios7, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView and i have made some custom cells to be my grid main menu. I have override the sizeForItemAtIndexPath method for resizing cells but the the image view inside the cell remains in the same size as it is (in the size inspector i suppose).

Also i have tried to resize imageview in cellForItemAtIndexPath() but nothing happened.

**MainMenuViewCell.m**

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self)
  {
     self.menuImage=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

     //i have tried here to resize it but nothing was happened

     [self.contentView insertSubview:self.menuImage atIndex:0];
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)prepareForReuse
{
   [super prepareForReuse];
   [self.menuImage setImage:nil];
   [self setNeedsLayout];
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];       
   self.contentView.bounds=CGRecctMake(0,0,self.bounds.size.width,self.bounds.size.width);
   menuImage.frame=CGRecctMake(0,0,self.bounds.size.width,self.bounds.size.width);
}
```

**MainMenuController.m**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPAth
{
   MainMenuViewCell *itemCell=(MainMenuViewCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIntifier:@"menuItem" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   itemCell.menuImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];

   return itemCell;
}

-(CGSize*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:collectionViewLayout  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPAth
{
   return screen width / 2;
}
```